# Rotate a vector by a given angle in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

How would I a vector contained in a list by a given angle. The vector/list contains two elements denoting x coordinate and y coordinate.

Consider the list to be independent of any turtle/patch components and I wish to implement a more generic way of vector rotation.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rotating a vector denoting turtle position by an angle Netlogo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25304332/rotating-a-vector-denoting-turtle-position-by-an-angle-netlogo)

Comment: The `rotate` reporter in [TurtleZero's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25313128/487946) does just that.